# How to even out a few text-boxes in stack-panel in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have 7 text-boxes containing weekday's names from Monday to Sunday. My problem is that I want to put each of those in a textbox inside the stack panel and get them to fill the entire stack panel horizontally so that each textbox has the same width.

How can that be achieved instead of the picture below of my attempt?

[image]

Comment: You should of course replace the StackPanel by a UniformGrid, not add one as a child of the StackPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `WrapPanel` instead and specify a minimum `ItemWidth`

```
<WrapPanel ItemWidth="140">
    <TextBlock Text="Monday"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Tuesday"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Wednesday"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Thursday"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Friday"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Saturday"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Sunday"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: Far better: `<UniformGrid Rows="1">`

Comment: thanks but when I resize the window it doesn't reformat to fill  the panel

Comment: @Euler As said, use a UniformGrid.

Comment: @Clements, still it won't work but I just replaced the stackpanel with a Grid and defined one row and 7 columns. Then I assigned each day a column from 0 to 6 and it woks fine. thanks guys anyway